# How can I create an elliptic torus in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, shapes, 3d

I know how to create a 3D torus in Adobe Indesign, this shape is generated by revolving a circle about an axis.

[image: Torus]

But how can I make an elongated/elliptical torus using Indesign, still with a circular cross-section?

[image: Ellipse]

Comment: Indesign is not really a drawing application, have you tried Illustrator? Then it would be easier to just import to ID.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can draw it from scratch, but that's a demanding job. I skip it.

When the watching direction is tilted an perpendicular with the main axis of the perimeter ellipse, the same apparent shape can be also got with circular torus.

It does not need to be exactly perpendicular, several degrees, for me at least 20 degrees, off is easily tolerated due the inaccuracy of the sight. That's of course of an opinion. But check my last attached image. Can you see it's not a circular torus?

For arbitary watching directions you must jump to a real 3D program. There you make your shape like these images show:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The images are made with Design Spark Mechanical. It's quite easy to use freeware without any material textures nor light condition adjustments. You can get the result into Adobe's software as a only in a basic way rendered bitmap, wireframe or also in several 3D formats. I've exported 3D shapes several times as OBJ files which are still rotatable and colorable in Photoshop. Exports as 3D PDF facets is possible, but I have used it only to see it works (=one can zoom and rotate the result in Adobe Reader).

Unfortunately I do not know how to use 3D PDFs in Indesign or web pages nor how to use Acrobat Pro to insert a 3D PDF to a normal PDF document.

Comment: Thanks, but I need more than an apparent shape, because I will put a camera in the setting. Also thanks for the tip about Design Spark M, but Im using a Mac.

Comment: Always my best compliments for your work.